# How do the Python masters recognise and examine contents of Python 3 data structures?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a noob to Python.

I constantly find myself looking at a piece of code and trying to work out what is inside a data structure such as for example a dictionary.  In fact the first thing I am trying to work out is "what sort of data structure is this?" and THEN I try to work out how to see what is inside it.  I look at a variable and say "is this a dict, or a list, or a multidict or something else I'm not yet familiar with?".  Then, "What's inside it?". It's consuming vast amounts of time and I just don't know if I'm taking the right approach.

So, the question is, "How do the Python masters find out what sort of data structure something is, and what techniques do they use to see what is inside those data structures?"

I hope the question is not too general but I'm spending ridiculous amounts of time just trying to fix issues with recognizing data structures and viewing their contents, let alone getting useful code written.

thanks heaps.

Comment: All three answers here are very good, although they do have somewhat different approaches, you should select which one seems to be most useful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using type() function for the variable will tell you the data type. For example:

```
inventory = {'cows': 4, 'pigs': 3, 'chickens': 5, 'bears': 2}
print(type(inventory))
```

will print

`<class 'dict'>`

which means the variable inventory is a dictionary.

Other possible data types are 'str' for string, 'int' for integer, 'float' for float,'tuple' for tuple, and 'bool' for boolean values.

To see what's inside a collection, you can simply use print() function.

```
aList = [ 'hunger', 'anger', 'burger']
print(aList)
```

will output

```
['hunger', 'anger', 'burger']
```

Comment: Don't forget the `pprint` module!

Answer (score 2):

I usually care more about how a type is /used/ than what exactly a type is.

For example, if an object is used with say:

```
foo["hey"] = "there"
for key, value in foo.items():
    print key, '->', value
```

Then I assume that 'foo' is some kind of dict-like object, and unless I have reason to investigate further, that's all I care about.

(Note: I'm still in python 2.x land, the syntax is slightly different in python 3.x, however the point remains)

Comment: Do you ever try to get the length of something to work out what is in it?

Comment: Only if I want to find out how long it is.

Answer (score 2):

In stead of "what is this?", with Python it can be better to ask "what does this do?" or "how is this used?". If you see something indexed, such as `a['foo']`, it shouldn't matter whether it is a dictionary or some other object, but simply that it is indexable by a string.

This idea is usually referred to as Duck Typing, so searching for this might give you some useful info. A quick search turned up this article, which seems relevant for you:
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/duck_typing.shtml

Answer (score 2):

I put an `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` in the relevant place, and once in the debugger I use `dir()`, `.__dict__` and `pp`, or any other forms of inspection necessary.

Comment: What do these things do for you?  What benefit would I gain in this approach in trying to find out what is going on in the code I am examining? thanks.

Comment: @DukeDougal: They help me figure out what's going on. The benefit is that it works and it's quick. *You* need to think less and do more. :-)